# Counting distinct id's grouped by a different id producing incorrect count's

Tags: sql, sqlite

I have an SQLite database table that has a similar structure to the following...

```
name     MicrosoftId     EventId

red      1               10001
blue     1               10001
green    2               10001
blue     2               10001
grey     3               10001

red      4               10002
green    5               10002
blue     5               10002

etc...
```

...and I am using the following query to generate some data about the table:

```
SELECT EventId as 'event', COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as 'size',
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'red',
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'blue',
SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'green'
FROM TagsMSCV 
WHERE name IN ('red','blue','green')
GROUP BY EventId
```

The bit that is going wrong is the 'size' column I'm making. It's supposed to be how many **unique** MicrosoftId's are in an EventId. So for the above example, EventId 10001 should be a size of 3, and EventId 10002 should be a size of 2.

The SQL I have written works without error, but the size's from COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) are all wrong and I can't figure out why. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: On a sidenote: Single quotes are delimiters for string literals. For names use double quotes, e.g. `SELECT EventId as "event"`, or remove them completely where not necessary, e.g. `SELECT EventId as event`.

Comment: On another sidenote: You may want to add an `ORDER BY` clause. While you may get sorted results already, this is not guaranteed to stay so without an explicit `ORDER BY`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is your `WHERE` clause. It removes all colors except 'red', 'blue', and 'green', so you don't count the other colors.
Remove the `WHERE` clause and you are fine.

**UPDATE:** You only want to show events that have at least one entry for red, green or blue. So add a `HAVING` clause or put your query in a subquery in order to use `WHERE`. Here are some options:

### HAVING with separate conditions:

```
SELECT 
  EventId as event,
  COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as size,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as red,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as blue,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as green
FROM TagsMSCV 
GROUP BY EventId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
    OR SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 
ORDER BY event;
```

### HAVING with one compound condition:

```
SELECT 
  EventId as event,
  COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as size,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as red,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as blue,
  SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as green
FROM TagsMSCV 
GROUP BY EventId
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN name IN ('red', 'blue', 'green') THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
ORDER BY event;
```

### WHERE on separate conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    EventId as event,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as size,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as red,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as green
  FROM TagsMSCV 
  GROUP BY EventId
) q
WHERE red > 0 OR blue > 0 OR green > 0
ORDER BY event;
```

### WHERE on a compound condition:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
  SELECT 
    EventId as event,
    COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as size,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as red,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as blue,
    SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as green
  FROM TagsMSCV 
  GROUP BY EventId
) q
WHERE red + blue + green > 0
ORDER BY event;
```

Comment: Oh right, that was to try remove cases where there is none of the colours I'm looking for in an event. Is there any other way to filter them out with SQL?

Comment: Yes, add a `HAVING` clause on the sums: `HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0 OR ...`. (Or move the whole query into a subquery: `select * from (query) q where red > 0 or blue > 0 or green > 0` or `select * from (query) q where red + blue + green > 0`.)

Comment: Hi, thank you for your help. However I am encountering syntax errors trying to use HAVING. Could you possibly edit your answer with a full example of what the syntax should be?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with `WHERE` clause, your `WHERE` clause filter out the name hence the `count()` will count only filtered names which are `'red','blue','green'`.

So, just remove the `WHERE` clause :

```
SELECT EventId as 'event', COUNT(DISTINCT MicrosoftId) as 'size',
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'red' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'red',
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'blue' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'blue',
       SUM(CASE WHEN name = 'green' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as 'green'
FROM TagsMSCV 
GROUP BY EventId;
```

Comment: Oh right, that was to try remove cases where there is none of the colours I'm looking for in an event. Is there any other way to filter them out with SQL?